# E353 nothing in register *

Tags: vim, zsh, tmux, spf13vim

After I added following line to `.tmux.conf` , I cannot `yy` and `p` in vim any more.

```
bind -t vi-copy Enter copy-pipe "xclip -i -selection clipboard"
```

now I removed this line from `.tmux.conf`, This error message still show up when I enter `p` (after `dd` or `yy`). It happened when I use vim inside tmux (outside tmux is fine). How to fix that?

Comment: I figure out why that happened. outside tmux the vim is `/usr/bin/vim` inside tmux it's `/usr/local/bin/vim`, the last one with `+clipboard`. how to fix this bug for `/usr/local/bin/vim` ?

Comment: Make sure `/usr/local/bin` appears in your `PATH` before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: If I want to use `/usr/local/bin/vim`, how can I use the default clipboard?

Comment: This may or may not be relevant: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/203